# Shouldn't we have a tag for bluegrass?

Tags: discussion, tags

Shouldn't we have a tag for bluegrass? There are tags for Blues and Rock-n-Roll, rightly so. I asked in [What's going on in Soldier's Joy?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/whats-going-on-in-soldiers-joy) whether we should also have this tag.

Answer (score 7):

Tags are generally created as needed, not because we could have questions with a particular tag. In the past we have typically waited until a few questions have been asked that may benefit from having a tag created for them.

Your Soldier's Joy question is off topic here anyway, so up until now we have no questions that require a bluegrass tag.

Comment: Well stated. +1 for past precedents.